# Dropdowns get cutoff inside table with overflow-x auto

Tags: jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2013

I have a series of tables that have dropdown menus in some of the TD's, all the tables have the overflow-x set to auto so the user can scroll horizontally if the table content is wider than the screen width.

You can see in the captures, apparently the overflow-x auto is causing the dropdowns to get cutoff even when their z-index is bigger than the tables.

[image: dropdown gets cutoff]

div containing the table css:

```
.ms-webpart-zone.ms-fullWidth .ms-webpartzone-cell {
   display: block;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: visible;
   min-height: 220px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Dropdown css:

```
top: 10px;
position: absolute;
visibility: visible;
left: 88px;
width: 226px;
```

[image]

I can't cut and paste a lot of code as this is a SharePoint app so my action field regarding customize css and especially html is limited.

Comment: seems you main parent has overflow: hidden which is causing the issue for the dropdown. if you give some demo code of you html or create fiddle we can understand.

Comment: @Chilll007 The main parent have these two properties overflow-x: auto;  overflow-y: visible. You can see that on the code i pasted in the original question. That's causing that the dropdown get cut off but i can't change that since is the behaviour intended. If the table width inside the layout is bigger than the parent div then it creates a scroll, same thing with height.

Comment: As per the 2nd image I can see that the dropdown is not default browser dropdown but custom created one. In that case when it comes inside the scroll the dropdown will be always inside the table scroll even if you increase the z-index.

Comment: @Tom, I don't know what do you mean with "default browser dropdown" but as i said on the original post this is Sharepoint. The second part of your answer is very debatable.

Comment: hi, if understand right, you are trying to implement a hovering dropdown which will: 1) stay visible/above all other elements(div, table) and 2) not cause an overflow effect when it does not fit into the table's parent div. also, from your comment *The problem is not the position of the dropdowns but the fact that they display inside the table and not like an absolutely position element (as you can see in the second image the dropdown generates a vertical scroll on the div)*, I'm not an expert but the fact that it's absolutely positioned does not mean it won't affect the overflow bars...

Comment: ...it is absolutely position but it is still *inside* its closest parent with `position: relative`, have you considered adding some extra calculations and prevent it from appearing somewhere that messes up the scroll bars, I mean, calculate, before it appears, if it will have a part outside the parent div and re-position it before it is actually rendered, this way you can keep all your current css, got it?

Comment: The solution for problems like this is to move the popups _outside_ the parent, perhaps append them to `body`. M$ not good with HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with your drop-down:

```
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: depend on your parent element of dropdown
left: the same with top
```

Comment: thanks @DüngKon but is not working, the dropdown still causes a scroll on the container div instead of just showing on top of the div with the overflow-x auto without changing the height of the container div.

Comment: What is position of parent html element? position:absolute only works if parent is position:absolute or position:relative.

Answer (score 1):

The parent body hides the overflow contents by default. So just give a style to the parent  **style="overflow:visible"** . In your case I guess the parent will be the grey box. Inspect the page and make sure you find the right parent that blocks the drop down.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the dropdown CSS as below:

```
top: 10px;
position: absolute;
visibility: visible;
left: 150px;
width: 226px;
bottom:50px;
```

Comment: The problem is not the position of the dropdowns but the fact that they display inside the table and not like an absolutely position element (as you can see in the second image the dropdown generates a vertical scroll on the div which is not the behaviour that i want).

Answer (score 0):

Does position: fixed on drop down helps?

```
top: 10px;
position: fixed;
visibility: visible;
left: 88px;
width: 226px;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @August.  I tried that and it works, the dropdown dont get cutted off BUT when you scroll down the page with the dropdown still visible the dropdown will follow you which is the normal behaviour for a fixed position element and that's a problem. I've been trying to find a way for the dropdown to have position fixed relative to the <th> of the table but i guess thats a position absolute solution and i already have that.

Comment: Yes, that I was trying to find out, exactly what you were saying. Based on this info I would say leave it as absolute, and try to investigate more about ancestors of the drop down menu, especially the one with overflow on it if it is getting modified in width/height when the dropdown is closed/open, you might debug that by listening to changes in debugger/sources of developer tools in chrome. You might have something dynamic shipped with sharepoint which does that.

Comment: Hey @August i was trying to figure out if there are any changes injected via JQuery on the dropdown ancestors and there are no changes related to height or width but as soon as i delete de "overflow-x:auto" property of the main ancestor div then the dropdown act like a regular "posibion absolute" element and the problem dissapear, so i don't know what else to do, i really need those boxes to scroll as soon as they are bigger than the page container.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your main-wrapper around the table, is "over" your dropdown. 
Would make sense, looking at your two screenshots.

The dropdown's not cut off, the grey square around your table - containing "Workflows > Viabilidad..." - just lays in front of it and probably has a higher z-index or sth.

Check this grey wrapper. Maybe make it opaque to see what's going on "behind".

Comment: Hey @Foaster, you were right, i change the z-index of the grey container around the table to a lower one and now is working BUT still having problems with IE11 due to position fixed of the dropdown, i used -ms-device-fixed which apparently is a solution but still have a really weird dropdown behaviour where part of the dropdown is under the other containers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function (e) {
if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
    $('.table-responsive').css('overflow-x', 'visible')
} else {
    $('.table-responsive').css('overflow-x', 'auto')
}})

$(document).on('click', 'body', function (e) {
    $('.table-responsive').css('overflow-x', 'auto') })
```